# Pagination does not work on first load in mat-paginator (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, pagination, angular7, paginator

I am using mat-paginator to paginate my tables. However, the pagination does not work the first time the page is loaded. However if I perform an operation on table like delete/edit a row, then the pagination starts working. I think it's because the paginator is not being fed with the values on first load. But I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

```
export class ProjectDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  public projects = [];
  public noProject = true;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['projectName', 'description', 'action'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IProjectData>;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
     private _projectService: ProjectService,
     private request: RequestService,
     private router: Router,
     public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
     private dialogService: ConfirmationDialogService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.listProject();
  }

  listProject() {
    const responseSubr = this.request.get<Array<IProject>>('projects');
    responseSubr.subscribe(result => {
      this.projects = result;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IProjectData>(result);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      if (this.projects.length === 0) {
        this.noProject = true;
      } else {
        this.noProject = false;
      }
    });
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddProjectDialogComponent, {
      width: '500px'
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listProject();
    });
  }

  openEditDialog(project): void {
    const projectData = project;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditProjectComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data : projectData
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.listProject();
    });

  }

  public deleteProject(project: IProject) {
    const msg = 'Are you sure to delete this project ?';
    this.dialogService.openConfirmDialog(msg)
    .afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      if (res)  {
        this._projectService.deleteProject(project.projectId)
      .subscribe(projects => {
        this.listProject();
      });
      }
    });
  }

  public onViewClick(project: IProject) {
    this.router.navigate(['/components', project.projectId]);
}
}
```

I tried placing the `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` line in ngOnInit() before the call to `listProject()` but that did not help.

Comment: hi use ngAfterViewInt hook for you pagination datasoucre   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

Comment: @upinderkumar Tried that already, with `this.listProject();` called inside ngOnInit() and `this.data.source.paginator = this.paginator` inside ngAfterViewInit(), outcome is the same.

Comment: can you please show me your html template

Comment: Please check my answer it will help because i am tried its work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  listProject() {

    setTimeout(() =>
    const responseSubr = this.request.get<Array<IProject>>('projects');
    responseSubr.subscribe(result => {
      this.projects = result;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IProjectData>(result);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      if (this.projects.length === 0) {
        this.noProject = true;
      } else {
        this.noProject = false;
      }
    });
);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to ngAfterViewInit()? Where do I place this code?

Comment: Thank you, your initial solution worked when I used it inside the subscribe method.

Comment: @Inception Welcome